# Rails: "Next post" and "Previous post" links in my show view, how to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new in Rails... smile

In my blog aplication I want to have a "Previous post" link and a "Next post" link in the bottom of my show view.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If each title is unique and you need alphabetical, try this in your `Post` model.

```
def previous_post
  self.class.first(:conditions => ["title < ?", title], :order => "title desc")
end

def next_post
  self.class.first(:conditions => ["title > ?", title], :order => "title asc")
end
```

You can then link to those in the view.

```
<%= link_to("Previous Post", @post.previous_post) if @post.previous_post %>
<%= link_to("Next Post", @post.next_post) if @post.next_post %>
```

Untested, but it should get you close. You can change `title` to any unique attribute (`created_at`, `id`, etc.) if you need a different sort order.

Comment: sorry Ryan, I must be going blind, your could :conditions => ["title > ? and id > ?", title, id] to work around. adding an index on title is kind of critical here unless its a toy app.

Comment: Slightly different syntax:
`self.class.where("today_date < ?", today_date).order(today_date: :desc).first`

Answer (score 15):

I used the model methods as below to avoid the issue where id + 1 doesn't exist but id + 2 does.

```rb
def previous
  Post.where(["id < ?", id]).last
end

def next
  Post.where(["id > ?", id]).first
end
```

In my view code, I just do this:

```html
<% if @post.previous %>
  <%= link_to "< Previous", @post.previous %>

<% if @post.next %>
  <%= link_to "Next >", @post.next %>
```

Answer (score 6):

My method will allow you to automatically use model scopes. For example, you may only want to display posts that are "published."

In your model:

```
def self.next(post)
  where('id < ?', post.id).last
end

def self.previous(post)
  where('id > ?', post.id).first
end
```

In your view

```
<%= link_to 'Previous', @posts.previous(@post) %>
<%= link_to 'Next', @posts.next(@post) %>
```

In your controller

```
@photos = Photo.published.order('created_at')
```

Associated RSpec tests:

```
describe '.next' do
  it 'returns the next post in collection' do
    fourth_post = create(:post)
    third_post = create(:post)
    second_post = create(:post)
    first_post = create(:post)

    expect(Post.next(second_post)).to eq third_post
  end

  it 'returns the next post in a scoped collection' do
    third_post = create(:post)
    decoy_post = create(:post, :published)
    second_post = create(:post)
    first_post = create(:post)

    expect(Post.unpublished.next(second_post)).to eq third_post
  end
end

describe '.previous' do
  it 'returns the previous post in collection' do
    fourth_post = create(:post)
    third_post = create(:post)
    second_post = create(:post)
    first_post = create(:post)

    expect(Post.previous(third_post)).to eq second_post
  end

  it 'returns the previous post in a scoped collection' do
    third_post = create(:post)
    second_post = create(:post)
    decoy_post = create(:post, :published)
    first_post = create(:post)

    expect(Post.unpublished.previous(second_post)).to eq first_post
  end
end
```

Note: there will be small issues when you reach the first/last post in a collection. I recommend a view helper to conditionally show the previous or next button only if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it. Firstly, add a couple of [named scopes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope) to your `Post` model:

```
def previous
  Post.find_by_id(id - 1, :select => 'title, slug etc...')
end

def next
  Post.find_by_id(id + 1, :select => 'title, slug etc...')
end
```

Note the use of the `:select` option to limit the fields because you probably don't want to retrieve a fully-populated `Post` instance just for showing the links.

Then in my `posts_helper` I have this method:

```
def sidebar_navigation_links
  next_post = @post.next
  previous_post = @post.previous
  links = ''
  if previous_post
    links << content_tag(:h3, 'Previous')
    links << content_tag(:ul, content_tag(:li,
                              content_tag(:a, previous_post.title,
                                          :href => previous_post.permalink)))
  end
  if next_post
    links << content_tag(:h3, 'Next', :class => 'next') if previous_post
    links << content_tag(:h3, 'Next') if previous_post.nil?
    links << content_tag(:ul, content_tag(:li,
                              content_tag(:a, next_post.title,
                                          :href => next_post.permalink)))
  end
  content_tag(:div, links)
end
```

I'm sure this could be refactored to be less verbose, but the intent is clear. Obviously your markup requirements will be different to mine, so you may not choose to use an unordered list, for example.

The important thing is the use of the `if` statements because if you're on the first post then they'll be no previous post and conversely, if you're on the last post they'll be no next post.

Finally, simply call the helper method from your view:

```
<%= sidebar_navigation_links %>
```

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your answer... but i have a problem.... 

If I destroy a post, I lose the consecutive ID and I would not know who is the next post or previous post, because  

Post.find_by_id(id - 1, :select => 'title, slug etc...')

other problem is that I don't have a permalink and i navigate in this moment by id but if I replace ":href => previous_post.permalink" by ":href => previous_post.id"

the href = emty
:)
can you help me?

thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Give the [will_paginate](http://wiki.github.com/mislav/will%5Fpaginate) Gem a try. It provides all the features you need to paginate your post entries. learn [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/51-will-paginate) too

You can look at [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=10&url=http%3A%2F%2Ferrtheblog.com%2Fposts%2F56-im-paginating-again&ei=QwSFSo7EAoPVkAW6lcGkBw&usg=AFQjCNGhvXk50_uQQGwXwrWXF3vA7ooRyA) too for example code if you want add next and previous buttons.

Comment: will_paginate is a poor fit for this problem. When you're showing a post you're dealing with an individual post, not a collection.

Answer (score 0):

I've created gem `proximal_records` especially for this kind of task and it works on any dynamically created scope in your model.

https://github.com/dmitry/proximal_records

Basic example:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ProximalRecords
end


scope = Article.title_like('proximal').order('created_at DESC, title ASC')
current_record = scope.to_a[5]
p, n = current_record.proximal_records(scope) # will find record 5 and 7
```

Answer (score -1):

You really just need to run 2 queries, one for each of "prev" and "next". Lets assume you have a created_at column.

Psuedo-code:

```
# get prev
select * from posts where created_at < #{this_post.created_at} order by created_at desc limit 1

# get next
select * from posts where created_at > #{this_post.created_at} order by created_at desc limit 1
```

Of course "this_post" is the current post.

If your posts are stored with an auto_increment column and you dont re-use IDs you can just use the id column in place of created_at - the id column should already be indexed. If you want to use the created_at column then you will definitely want to have an index on that column.

Comment: Yep, you're right, an order by is needed. I updated my response.

Comment: thak you!, but if need detect next or previous alphabetical :title post?