# Find Next and previous records ordered by position column rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
>>  c = Course.find(3).course_steps.order(:position)
=> [#<CourseStep id: 9, step_id: 4, course_id: 3, position: 1, created_at: "2011-03-08 20:57:44", updated_at: "2011-03-08 20:57:44">, #<CourseStep id: 10, step_id: 5, course_id: 3, position: 2, created_at: "2011-03-08 20:57:45", updated_at: "2011-03-08 20:57:45">, #<CourseStep id: 8, step_id: 2, course_id: 3, position: 3, created_at: "2011-03-08 20:57:42", updated_at: "2011-03-08 20:57:42">]
```

I need to find a course_step that is after id 9 (which happens to be course_step with id 10) (if it is exists)

I also need to find the previous (if it is exists)

I know I could manually do it be looping through the results, but I would rather do it with SQL.

The NEXT sql query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM course_steps WHERE position >=POSITION_OF_STEP ORDER BY position LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

The PREVIOUS sql query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM course_steps WHERE position <= POSITION_OF_STEP ORDER BY position DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

I think I got it!

Comment: Isn't your SQL example code simply getting a single CourseStep with position >= 1? How does this translate into a NEXT query?

Comment: I am just hard coding the position. I would have this information in code

Comment: Looks like you got it, but seems to me that if you want NEXT or PREVIOUS you probably want > and < instead of >= and <= in the position part of your where clause. You can also turn this into two very simple ruby functions that might be cleaner.

Comment: There is the case where the position of everything could be 1, so I want to make sure I cover that case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: "Next post" and "Previous post" links in my show view, how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275963/rails-next-post-and-previous-post-links-in-my-show-view-how-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CourseStep < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :step
  belongs_to :course

  validates_uniqueness_of :step_id, :scope => :course_id

  def next_step()
    Course.find(self.course.id).course_steps.order(:position).where("position >= ?", self.position).limit(1).offset(1).first
  end

  def previous_step()
     Course.find(self.course.id).course_steps.order("position DESC").where("position <= ?", self.position).limit(1).offset(1).first
  end
end
```