# Rails: Previous and Next record from previous query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, view

My app has photos, and users can search for photos that meet certain criteria. Let's say a user searches for photos by tag, and we get something like this:

```
@results = Photo.tagged_with('mountain')
```

Now, `@results` is going to be a standard activerecord query with multiple records. These would be shown in a grid, and a user can then click on a photo. This would take the users to the `photos#show` action.

So, lets say the user searches for something and the app finds 5 records, `[1,2,3,4,5]`, and the user clicks on photo #3.

On the `photo#show` page I'd like to be able to show a "Next Photo", "Previous Photo", and "Back to Search".

The only other constraint is, if the user browses to a photo directly (via another page or a bookmark etc) there wouldn't be a logical "next" and "previous" photo since there wasn't a query that led them to that photo, so in that case the template shouldn't render the query-related content at all.

So, I have been thinking about how to do this kind of thing and I don't really have a lot of good ideas. I suppose I could do something like store the query in session to be able to go back to it, but I don't know how to find the photos that would have shown up to the left and right of the selected photo.

Does anyone have any examples of how to do this kind of thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: "Next post" and "Previous post" links in my show view, how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275963/rails-next-post-and-previous-post-links-in-my-show-view-how-to)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, after much trial and error, here is what I came up with:

In my Photo model:

```
# NEXT / PREVIOUS FUNCTIONALITY
def previous(query)
  unless query.nil?
    index = query.find_index(self.id)
    prev_id = query[index-1] unless index.zero?
    self.class.find_by_id(prev_id)
  end
end

def next(query)
  unless query.nil?
    index = query.find_index(self.id)
    next_id = query[index+1] unless index == query.size
    self.class.find_by_id(next_id)
  end
end
```

This method returns the next and previous record from a search or a particular folder view by accepting an array of those records ids. I generate that ID in any controller view that creates a query view (ie the search page and the browse by folders page):

So, for instance, my search controller contains:

```
def search
  @search = @collection.photos.search(params[:search])
  @photos = @search.page(params[:page]).per(20)
  session[:query] = @photos.map(&:id)
end
```

And then the photo#show action contains:

```
if session[:query]
  @next_photo = @photo.next(session[:query])
  @prev_photo = @photo.previous(session[:query])
end
```

And lastly, my view contains:

```
- if @prev_photo || @next_photo
  #navigation
    .header Related Photos
    .prev
      = link_to image_tag( @prev_photo.file.url :tenth ), collection_photo_path(@collection, @prev_photo) if @prev_photo
      - if @prev_photo
        %span Previous
    .next
      = link_to image_tag( @next_photo.file.url :tenth ), collection_photo_path(@collection, @next_photo) if @next_photo
      - if @next_photo
        %span Next
```

Now it turns out this works great in regular browsing situations -- but there is one *gotcha* that I have not yet fixed:

Theoretically, if a user searches a view, then jumps to a photo they've generated a query in session. If, for some reason, they then browse directly (via URL or bookmark) to another photo that was part of the previous query, the query will persist in session and the related photos links will still be visible on the second photo -- even though they shouldn't be on a photo someone loaded via bookmark.

However, in real life use cases this situation has actually been pretty difficult to recreate, and the code is working very well for the moment. At some point when I come up with a good fix for that one remaining gotcha I'll post it, but for now if anyone uses this idea just be aware that possibility exists.

Comment: You could solve your _gotcha_ by putting the id of the persisted query in the url for the next / previous links and the links from the search page.  That way, if you see the ID and it matches the last persisted query, show the next / previous buttons.  If the ID isn't there because the user typed the URL or got to the page another way, don't show the buttons.

Comment: @Brian: Oooh! That's a cool idea, I'll work on implementing something like that!

Comment: Thanks ever so much for posting this, it's come in really useful.

Comment: What are you doing if you iterate over the number of given photos which are limited by @search.page(params[:page]).per(20) ?

Comment: To be honest that hasn't been an issue. The purpose of the next/previous in my app is basically to see nearby adjacent records meeting a given criteria, but there aren't usually very many. It would make sense to just reverse the order of assignment, though: store the photo map from search in session, then paginate it.

Answer (score 2):

Andrew, your method not universal and dont give guaranteed right result. There is better way to do this.
In your model:

```
def previous
  Photo.where('photos.id < ?', self.id).first
end

def next
  Photo.where('photos.id > ?', self.id).last
end
```

And in views:

```
- if @photo.previous
  = link_to 'Previous', @photo.previous
- if @photo.next
  = link_to 'Next', @photo.next
```

Comment: That does *not* do what I was trying to do. I don't just want the next photo, I want the next photo from the specific users most recent search results. I'm sure my method isn't perfect, and I listed my biggest known "gotcha" with it, but it does work as needed in my app.

Comment: It didn't do what he wanted, but it was perfect for me :)

Comment: For me, using Rails 4 this isn't working quite properly. Your "next" give me the "last" and "previous" give me the "first.

Comment: Got nothing to do with Rails 4, that code should do that. Replace `first` with `last` and vice versa, and you should get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

A gem I wrote called [Nexter](https://github.com/charly/nexter) does it for you.

You pass it an AR Scope combination (aka ActiveRelation) plus the current Object/Record and [Nexter](https://github.com/charly/nexter) will inspect the order clause  to build the sql that will fetch the before/previous and after/next records.

Basically it looks at the ActiveRelation#order_values in order(a, b, c) and comes out with :

```
# pseudo code
where(a = value_of a AND b = value of b AND c > value of c).or
where(a = value_of a AND b > value of b).or
where(a > value of a)
```

That's only the gist of it. It also works with association values and is clever with finding the inverse values for the previous part. To keep the state of your search (or scope combination) you can use another lib like [siphon](https://github.com/charly/siphon), ransack, has_scope etc...

Here's a [working example](https://github.com/charly/nexter#use-case-full-stack) from the README

The model :

```
class Book
  def nexter=(relation)
    @nexter = Nexter.wrap(relation, self)
  end

  def next
    @nexter.next
  end

  def previous
    @nexter.previous
  end
end
```

The controller

```
class BookController
  before_filter :resource, except: :index

  def resource
    @book_search = BookSearch.new(params[:book_search])

    @book ||= Book.includes([:author]).find(params[:id]).tap do |book|
      book.nexter = siphon(Book.scoped).scope(@book_search)
    end
  end
end
```

The view :

````
<%= link_to "previous", book_path(@book.previous, book_search: params[:book_search]) %>
<%= link_to "collection", book_path(book_search: params[:book_search]) %>
<%= link_to "next", book_path(@book.next, book_search: params[:book_search])
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at what done in [ActsAsAdjacent](https://github.com/scsmith/ActsAsAdjacent/blob/master/lib/acts_as_adjacent.rb):

```
named_scope :previous, lambda { |i| {:conditions => ["#{self.table_name}.id < ?", i.id], :order => "#{self.table_name}.id DESC"} }
named_scope :next, lambda { |i| {:conditions => ["#{self.table_name}.id > ?", i.id], :order => "#{self.table_name}.id ASC"} }
```

Essentially, they're scopes(pre Rails 3 syntax) to retrieve records that have IDs lesser/greater than the ID of the record you passed in.

Since they're scopes, you can chain previous with .first to get the first item created before the current item, and .tagged_with('mountain').first to get the first such item tagged with 'mountain'.