# How do I implement next and previous links along with their permalink

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pagination

I have a simple blog app. On my index page, where all the posts are show. What I want do is show only one post on one page and have next and previous links. When clicked on next, it should go to the next post based on created date and the url in the browser should be the actual link `/problems/:id` .

Any help of suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate answer from [Stack Overflow another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275963/rails-next-post-and-previous-post-links-in-my-show-view-how-to)

If each title is unique and you need alphabetical, try this in your Post model.

```
def previous_post
  self.class.first(:conditions => ["title < ?", title], :order => "title desc")
end

def next_post
  self.class.first(:conditions => ["title > ?", title], :order => "title asc")
end
```

You can then link to those in the view.

```
<%= link_to("Previous Post", @post.previous_post) if @post.previous_post %>
<%= link_to("Next Post", @post.next_post) if @post.next_post %>
```

Untested, but it should get you close. You can change title to any unique attribute `(created_at, id, etc.)` if you need a different sort order.

Comment: if i am right previous_post and new_post method go into the model right? and should @post hold or be equal to?

Comment: @post should get the id. So Previous id and next id for Previous post and next.