# Rails: Previous/Next in record when dealing with nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm able to show previous and next links in my application, but I'm trying to figure out what happens if my link has nested routes?

For example my link is

```
  localhost:3000/users/1/photos/2
```

I have these in my model:

```
  def previous_img
    self.class.first(:conditions => ["created_at < ?", created_at], :order => "created_at desc")
  end

  def next_img
    self.class.first(:conditions => ["created_at > ?", created_at], :order => "created_at asc")
  end
```

and in my views I have this:

```
  <%= link_to "Previous", @photo.previous_img if @photo.previous_img %>
  <%= link_to "Next", @photo.next_img if @photo.next_img %>
```

These links will direct me to a link without the `users/1` and it will just give me

```
  localhost:3000/photos/1 # for previous
  localhost:3000/photos/3 # for next
```

Is there a way, maybe, that I can concatenate the `users/1` or an actual way to get nested routes in this matter?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: "Next post" and "Previous post" links in my show view, how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275963/rails-next-post-and-previous-post-links-in-my-show-view-how-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `user_photo_path` to get a nested link:

```
<%= link_to "Previous", user_photo_path(@photo.user, @photo.previous_img) if @photo.previous_img %>
```

Comment: quick question. I realized that when there's no record with the user id, i get an error. Is there an easy way to only find the record with the user id?

Comment: Now I'm getting error when I'm trying to check another user's photo... I get a rake routing error. ie: `users/5/photos/6` and I checked that this link does work when I delete the links from the view file

Comment: It's passing an id nil `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"photos", :user_id=>5, :id=>nil}` and I changed `@photo.user` to `@photo.user_id` because thats the column name in my database