# Rails: Next/Previous button for images in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have images where you can click next and previous, but I'm having trouble because when I'm viewing the last image in my database (that is associated with user_id), it show's routing error with :id => nil.

This is happening because there's no more data after the image for that user. So how can I set it will rotate their images even if they get to their last image in database (if next), and vice versa, if previous.

This is in my model

```
  def self.s_prev(img)
    first(:conditions => ["created_at < ?", img.created_at], :order => "created_at desc")
  end

  def self.s_next(img)
    first(:conditions => ["created_at > ?", img.created_at], :order => "created_at asc")
  end
```

These is my links

```
<%= link_to "Previous", user_image_path(@image.user_id, @user.images.s_prev(@image)) if user_image_path(@image.user_id, @user.styles.s_prev(@image)) %>

<%= link_to "Next", user_image_path(@image.user_id, @user.images.s_next(@image)) if user_image_path(@image.user_id, @user.images.s_next(@image)) %>
```

Apparently the if statements don't help me, for some reason

Lets say there's these database id for images table:

```
id    user_id 
1       14
2       14
3       14
4       15
```

So say if I'm on this page: **localhost:3000/users/14/images/2**

The page will show, and the links will show, but when I click on next, I'll get an error because there is no user_id => 15 and id => 4, where the next button is trying to get `localhost:3000/users/14/images/4` for the page in `...users/14/images/3`

So how do I avoid this issue and only display next/previous links associated with user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: "Next post" and "Previous post" links in my show view, how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275963/rails-next-post-and-previous-post-links-in-my-show-view-how-to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def self.s_prev(img)
  ordered = scoped.order("created_at desc")
  ordered.first(:conditions => ["created_at < ?", img.created_at]) || ordered.first
end

def self.s_next(img)
  ordered = scoped.order("created_at asc")
  ordered.first(:conditions => ["created_at > ?", img.created_at]) || ordered.first
end
```