# Restrict link to previous record only if within same associated resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, link-to

I have Lesson and Word models, where a lesson has many words. In each lesson view, users can access show views for those words that belong to the lesson.

I've implemented "Previous" and "Next" links for my show view, following the ideas from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275963/rails-next-post-and-previous-post-links-in-my-show-view-how-to) post. However, the first word of a lesson shows a "Previous" link, which links to another lesson's last word; a lesson's last word similarly links to the first word of another lesson (the only exceptions are the database's very first and very last words). How can I restrict the previous/next links only to those words that belong to the current lesson?

Word model:

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lesson

  def previous
    Word.where(["id < ?", id]).last
  end

  def next
    Word.where(["id > ?", id]).first
  end
end
```

Word show view:

```
<div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
  <h1 class="text-center"><%= current_word.term %></h1><br>

  <%= image_tag(current_word.image, class: 'img-responsive') %><br>

  <p class="text-center">(<%= current_word.reference %>)</p><br>

  <%= link_to "< Previous", current_word.previous if current_word.previous %>
  <%= link_to "Next >", current_word.next if current_word.next %>
</div>
```

Words controller:

```
class WordsController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end

  private

    helper_method :current_word
    def current_word
      @current_word ||= Word.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do something like this in your view:

```
<% if current_word == Word.first %>
  <%= link_to "Next >", current_word.next if current_word.next %>
<% elsif current_word == Word.last %>
  <%= link_to "< Previous", current_word.previous if current_word.previous %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "< Previous", current_word.previous if current_word.previous %>
  <%= link_to "Next >", current_word.next if current_word.next %>
<% end %>
```

### Edit

So try,

```
<%= link_to "< Previous", current_word.previous if current_word.previous.lesson_id == current_word.lesson.id %>
<%= link_to "Next >", current_word.next if current_word.next.lesson_id == current_word.lesson.id %>
```

This way as soon as either next or previous words are from a different lesson, ie have a different lesson_id, the link will disappear.

Let me know if that works

Comment: This has a similar effect to what I had before. I tried calling the words lesson `if current_word == current_word.lesson.words.first` and that works to an extent. The actual linking will take the user to previous or next lessons in the order created regardless of whether they belong to the same lesson.

Comment: can you tag on a query for next and previous, something like ```if lesson.id == current_word.lesson_id``` ?

Comment: actually it would probably read better having ```unless lesson.id == current_word.lesson_id```

Comment: Would the query go in the view or in the model? methodsAppreciate the help, I'm still a newbie :)

Comment: To follow up, I noticed a bug when I create words in different lessons and come back. The functionality breaks if word id's are in nonsequential order. That is, it'll work for lesson words id 24 through 29, but if I then add a word with id 31 to that lesson it will not show the buttons.

Comment: Yeah I see the problem. The ```if``` statement I wrote is looking at the word.next or word.previous and finding it's lesson Id however, if there is a gap in id's, as you've mentioned above, the word.previous won't exist and so it will return a lesson_id of nil. Why don't you create a ```current_lesson``` helper method like you did for word, it would be written the same way. Then your ```if``` statement could be ```if current_lesson.id == current_word.lesson_id```