# redirect_to next instance on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect

I'm trying to redirect users to the next instance of my WordExposition model after update. What I have currently works for immediately-adjacent word_exposition id's, but raises `RecordNotFound` if the next lesson's word_exposition's ID skips (i.e. it will redirect properly between id's 1-4, but will break if the next id is 6). How can I get it to redirect also for those non-adjacent WordExposition instances that belong to the same lesson?

I based the `next_exposition` model method on the ideas from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275963/rails-next-post-and-previous-post-links-in-my-show-view-how-to) post, but I'm missing something to get it to work here.

WordExposition model:

```
class WordExposition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :enrollment
  belongs_to :word

  def next_exposition
    WordExposition.where(["id > ? AND enrollment_id = ?", id, enrollment_id]).first
  end
end
```

WordExpositions controller:

```
class WordExpositionsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    current_word_exposition
    @current_word_exposition.completed = true
    @current_word_exposition.term_given_by_student = params[:word_exposition][:term_given_by_student]
    if @current_word_exposition.save
      flash[:notice] = "Congratulations!"
      #currently only redirects correctly for adjacent words in the same lesson, should do so for non-adjacent word_expositions in the same lesson
      if next_word = @current_word_exposition.next_exposition
        redirect_to lesson_word_exposition_path(current_lesson, next_word)
      end 
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Enter the word exactly as shown!"
      redirect_to lesson_word_exposition_path(current_lesson, current_word_exposition)
    end
  end

  private

  helper_method :current_lesson
  def current_lesson
    @current_lesson ||= Lesson.find(params[:lesson_id])
  end

  helper_method :current_enrollment
  def current_enrollment
    @current_enrollment ||= Enrollment.find_by!(lesson_id: params[:lesson_id], user_id: current_user.id)
  end

  def word_exposition_params
    params.require(:word_exposition).permit(:completed)
  end

  helper_method :current_word_exposition
  def current_word_exposition
    @current_word_exposition ||= current_enrollment.word_expositions.find_by!(word_id: params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  def next_exposition
    WordExposition.where('id = (select min(id) from word_expositions where id > ?)', self.id).first
  end
```

Comment: This raises an exception on submission of the form: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in WordExpositionsController#update` `SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: items: SELECT "word_expositions".* FROM "word_expositions" WHERE (id = (select min(id) from items where id > 2)) ORDER BY "word_expositions"."id" ASC LIMIT 1` (I appreciate the help, newbie rails user here)

Comment: Try now, just don't copy the answer, see what the error is, it says `items` is not a table, I ran this query on a table `Item` which I had in my DB, I didn't have `word_expositions`, so look at the error and try to fix it

Comment: I understand--thanks for the hand! It's still trying to render a word_exposition that doesn't have an instance instead of skipping to the next one in the table (`Couldn't find WordExposition with [WHERE "word_expositions"."enrollment_id" = ? AND "word_expositions"."word_id" = ?]`)

Comment: Try query in the most basic form first, remove word_id and check